# Method is not allowed

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to create simple form with post. But when i submit my form i get this error - `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

My route file:

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
Route::get('articles/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');

Route::post('articles', 'ArticlesController@store');
```

Form:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'articles', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('body', 'Body:') !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Add article', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller class:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $input = $request->all();

        return $input;
    }
```

Thanks for your attention. I dont get where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer. Just type `php artisan route:clear` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same `url` both in `Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@index');` and `Route::post('articles', 'ArticlesController@store');`

Use `action()` instead of `url` can solve this problem. EX:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ArticlesController@store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the route: `Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@index'); to Route::post('articles', 'ArticlesController@index');`